# Core Plot - Determining pixel size of plot area to plot a huge data set

Tags: ios, core-plot

So I'm plotting about 80k records in CorePlot and it is kind of slow.  I realized, however, that the pixel density of my graph zoomed out is obviously not 80k pixels.  I'd like to be able to preform a data reduction on my data depending on zoom range so I have no more than 1 point per pixel but I'm having trouble determining how to find out the frame size of the plot area.

Is there a way to do this programmatically.  What i've done is save a screen shot of the graph from the iPhone simulator and trace out the **Plot Area** graph area by hand and I come up with about:  1760x1116

I'd love to know if there is a way to do this from code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot area (and many other parts of a Core Plot graph) are `CALayer` objects. Get the `bounds` of that layer and inspect the `size` field. If you have a reference to a plot, you can use this:

```
CGSize plotAreaSize = plot.plotArea.bounds.size;
```

If not, you can also get to the plot area from the graph:

```
CGSize plotAreaSize = graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea.bounds.size;
```

Comment: This is incorrect:  plot.plotArea.frame.bounds.size Please update your answer if you want credit.